# JAXB Unmarshalling XML

Tags: java, jaxb

Имеется XML:

```
<getNewLNNumRangeResponse xmlns="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/eln/mo/v01" xmlns:ns2="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/eln/v01" xmlns:ns3="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/eln/ins/v01" xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/fault/v01" xmlns:ns6="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/common/v01">
<ns2:requestId>LNNUMMO_1024201477520_2022_05_26_00072</ns2:requestId>
<ns2:status>1</ns2:status>
<ns2:mess>OK</ns2:mess>
<data>
<ns2:lnCode>900000672560</ns2:lnCode>
<ns2:lnCode>900000672561</ns2:lnCode>
<ns2:lnCode>900000672562</ns2:lnCode>
</data>
</getNewLNNumRangeResponse>
```

Пытаюсь размаршалить в модели при помощи JAXB.
Модели:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "getNewLNNumRangeResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "data"
})
public class GetNewLNNumRangeResponse
    extends WSResult
{
    
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected LnCodeList data;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the data property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link LnCodeList }
     *     
     */

    public LnCodeList getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the data property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link LnCodeList }
     *     
     */

    public void setData(LnCodeList value) {
        this.data = value;
    }

}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LnCodeList", propOrder = {
    "lnCode"
})
public class LnCodeList {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> lnCode;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lnCode property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the lnCode property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getLnCode().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<String> getLnCode() {
        if (lnCode == null) {
            lnCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.lnCode;
    }

}
```

Собственно пытаюсь выгрузить список, а он пустой:

```
List<String> lnCode = getNewLNNumRangeResponse.getData().getLnCode();
```

Проблема как мне кажется в аннотациях, чего-то не хватает. Не пойму чего только.

**Обновление.**
В XML содержится много другой информации, цифровая подпись. Расшарить полностью документ не получится.

В модель попадает все кроме блока data. Он имеет значение null.

**Обновление.**
По совету **ulxanxv**, Добавил `@XmlJavaAdapterType` на поле и смог получить значение, но выглядит как велосипед не понятно почему он не подставляет сразу как нужно...

```
public class XmlAdapterTest extends XmlAdapter<Object, LnCodeList> {

    public Object marshal(LnCodeList boundType) throws   Exception {
         return (LnCodeList) boundType;
    } 

    public LnCodeList unmarshal(Object valueType) throws Exception {
        LnCodeList lnCodeList = new LnCodeList();
        List<String> draft = new ArrayList<String>();
        ElementNSImpl ns = (ElementNSImpl) valueType;
        for(int index = 0; index < ns.getChildNodes().getLength(); index++) {
            Node item = ns.getChildNodes().item(index);
            draft.add(item.getTextContent());
        }
        lnCodeList.setLnCode(draft);
        return lnCodeList;
    } 
}
```

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlAdapterTest.class)
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected LnCodeList data;
```

Не знаю можно ли это считать ответом, но работает.

Comment: Ощущение есть что какой то XML у вас не верный

Comment: Если не получается распарить Ваш XML, то обычно ошибки будут лететь, а тут их нет. Может быть он просто не видит эти поля по причине того, что неверный XML?

Comment: А что у вас за интересный момент написан? `required = true, nillable = true`. Как оно может быть обязательно и не обязательно одновременно

Comment: Ну не совсем так, required - обязательное, nillable - может быть пустым. То есть как блок он обязателен, но внутри блока может ничего не находится.

Comment: а если блок не придёт и будет `null`, то как программа вообще отреагирует?

Comment: В случае когда придет null, в getter написана логика создания пустого списка new ArrayList<>(). Причем все эти модели были сгенерированы на основе xsd схемы сервиса.

Comment: ну так если всё автоматически были сгенерировано, то тогда вряд ли в конфигурации есть какие то проблемы. скорее всего проблема с присылаемым xml

Comment: И ещё один момент интересный.  У вас `LnCodeList` не реализует интерфейс `Serializable` и нет `serialVersionUID`. Может быть тоже может быть проблема из-за этого :/ Я на самом деле в этом плохо разбираюсь, просто идеи накидываю

Comment: Обычно всё таки с JSON работать приходиться)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Думаю в данном случае сериализация необязательна, но я попробовал, не помогло)

Comment: Штош, попробуйте тогда написать свой собственный `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` и посмотреть что вообще вам там приходит в этом поле)

Comment: Может надо просто указать `namespace` : `@XmlElement(namespace="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/eln/v01") protected List<String> lnCode;`? `<ns2:lnCode>` и `<lnCode>` - это как бы разные теги

Comment: Да, Sergey, вы абсолютно правы. Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "getNewLNNumRangeResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GetNewLNNumRangeResponse", propOrder = {
    "data"
})
public class GetNewLNNumRangeResponse
    extends WSResult
{
    
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected LnCodeList data;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the data property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link LnCodeList }
     *     
     */

    public LnCodeList getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the data property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link LnCodeList }
     *     
     */

    public void setData(LnCodeList value) {
        this.data = value;
    }

}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LnCodeList", propOrder = {
    "lnCode"
})
public class LnCodeList {

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/eln/v01")
    protected List<String> lnCode;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the lnCode property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the lnCode property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getLnCode().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    
    public void setLnCode(List<String> lnCode) {
        this.lnCode = lnCode;
    }
    
    public List<String> getLnCode() {
        if (lnCode == null) {
            lnCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.lnCode;
    }

}
```

**Место исправления:**

```
@XmlElement(namespace="http://www.fss.ru/integration/types/eln/v01") 
protected List<String> lnCode;
```

Спасибо, Sergey!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]